# how i get the result of listbox tkinter to valeu

Tags: python, tkinter

i have problem with this

```
def xxx():
        n=ent1.get()
        if n.isnumeric()==True:
                n=int(n)
                for i in range(0, n):
                    global x
                    x=[]
                    for i in range(1):
                        x.append(random_phone_num_generator())
                        print(x)
                    lst1.insert(END,x)
```

i have same other function
i went to use x variable in other fucntion but hi return the last valeu of x list

```
def save_file():
      for i in range(len(x)):
          print(x[i])
```

but he give me the last one of list
the random_phone_num_generator() its reutrn function

Comment: (1) Create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show it as properly formatted code in the question. (2) Decide for one Python version and remove the other tag.

Comment: What is `ent1`? Is it a widget, or an `IntVar`, or something else? Have you verified that `n` is what you expect, both in type and in value?

Comment: `x` is a list with only one element.

Answer (score 0):

You have reset `x` to empty list in each iteration of the outer for loop, so finally `x` is just a list with only one item.

You need to reset `x` before the outer for loop and you don't need the inner for loop at all:

```py
def xxx():
    global x
    n = ent1.get()
    if n.isnumeric() == True:
        n = int(n)
        x = []
        for i in range(n):
            phone_num = random_phone_num_generator()
            x.append(phone_num)
            print(x)
            # I think you want to insert the random phone number instead of x
            lst1.insert(END, phone_num)
```